# Node Express Passport app 404ing when trying to login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to figure out why my app is 404ing when I login. The proper index page loads however, from there /login 404s. The stack error isn't at all helpful and just references the error handler in app.js. To try remedy this I tried putting my login.jade template in every directory I thought it could be referencing to no avail. This must mean there's something wrong with the way I'm routing everything but I've tripple checked everything a few times. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: After more troubleshooting, there had got to be something wrong with the way /login is routed. My app doesn't seem to care if auth has a valid path when requiring it.

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var auth = require('./auth')
var app = express();

// load mongoose package
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserModel = require('./models/User');
UserModel.init();


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var todos = require('./routes/todos');



// Use native Node promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todo-api')
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection succesful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({secret: '56950fe494af8e88204adf6d', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/todos', todos);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
module.exports = app;
```

Routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = require('../auth');
var controllers = require('../controllers');
var app = express();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'ngTodo' });
});

app.get('/register', controllers.users.getRegister);
app.post('/register', controllers.users.createUser);

app.post('/login', auth.login);
app.get('/logout', auth.logout);
app.get('/login', controllers.users.getLogin);

app.get('/client', function (req, res) {
  res.render('../views/client/index', {currentUser: req.session.user});
});

app.get('/error', function (req, res) {
  res.render('..views/error')
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {currentUser: req.user});
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {currentUser: req.user});
});

module.exports = router;
```

UserController.js

```
var encryption = require('../utilities/cripto'),
    usersData = require('../models/usersData');

module.exports = {
    getRegister: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.user) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }

        else {
            res.render('users/register');
        }
    },
    createUser: function (req, res, next) {
        var newUserData = req.body;

        if (newUserData.password !== newUserData.confirmPassword) {
            req.session.error = 'Passwords do not match!';
            res.redirect('/register');
        }

        else {
            newUserData.salt = encryption.generateSalt();
            newUserData.hashPass = encryption.generateHashedPassword(newUserData.salt, newUserData.password);
            usersData.createUser(newUserData, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    req.session.error = 'Username exists!';
                    res.redirect('/register');
                    return;
                }

                req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(400);
                        return res.send({reason: err.toString()});
                    }

                    else {
                        res.redirect('/');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    },
    updateUser: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.user._id == req.body._id || req.user.roles.indexOf('admin') > -1) {
            var updatedUserData = req.body;
            if (updatedUserData.password && updatedUserData.password.length > 0) {
                updatedUserData.salt = encryption.generateSalt();
                updatedUserData.hashPass = encryption.generateHashedPassword(updatedUserData.salt, updatedUserData.password);
            }

            if (updatedUserData.password !== updatedUserData.confirmPassword) {
                req.session.error = 'Passwords do not match!';
                res.redirect('/profile');
            } else {
                usersData.updateUser({_id: req.body._id}, updatedUserData, function (err, user) {
                    res.redirect('/profile');
                })
            }
        }
        else {
            res.send({reason: 'You do not have permissions!'})
        }
    },
    getLogin: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.user) {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        else {
            res.render('users/login');
        }
    },
    getProfile: function (req, res, next) {
        if (!req.user) {
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            res.render('profile/profile', {currentUser: req.user, userToUpdate: req.user});
        }
    }
};
```

Auth.js

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {
    login: function(req, res, next) {
        var auth = passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            if (!user) {
                req.session.error = 'Invalid Username or Password!';
                res.redirect('/');
            }

            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.redirect('/client');
                console.log();
            })
        });

        auth(req, res, next);
    },
    logout: function(req, res, next) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    },
    isAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    isInRole: function(role) {
        return function(req, res, next) {
            if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.roles.indexOf(role) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter here for a test app but I would encourage the habit of removing your secret tokens from public code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `Routes.js` file you have

```
var controllers = require('../controllers');
```

But then your controller file name is actually `UserController.js`

Can you please try updating to

```
var controllers = require('../UserController');
```

On a side note, try and [stick with lowercase for naming](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#stick-with-lowercase) to keep your life simple.

Comment: 'Thank you. That got us somewhere. It says "cannot read property of getRegister undefined".

Comment: I fixed that and we are back to square one. That was the correct route for controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `routes.js` doesn't make sense: you're creating both an Express router *and* an app, and attach most of the route handlers (apart from the handler for `/`) to the app. At the end, you export the router (which only handles `/`).